# libgdx/android: actor becomes black after added to stage

Tags: android, libgdx, stage

In certain specific cases an actor after being added to the stage becomes a black surface, instead of the actual texture. In the other cases I could load the actor at the beginning, then set it invisible and when I need it, I could set it visible. But I don't want to do that.

So here's the code of render():

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(backgroundColour.r, backgroundColour.g, backgroundColour.b,
        backgroundColour.a);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

and where I try to add the image to the stage

```
cardImage.setPosition(x, y);
cardImage.setWidth(ViewConstants.scalingWidthCard * ViewConstants.widthOneSpace);
cardImage.setHeight(ViewConstants.scalingHeightCard * ViewConstants.heightOneSpace);
stage.addActor(cardImage);
```

where cardImage is of class `ImageWrapper` (ImageWrapper extends Image and simply holds some more fields, methods were not overwritten/changed in any way). And here is the code how I load the texture:

```
private ImageWrapper loadActorForCardAndSaveInMap(Card card) {
    String textureString = loader.getCardTextureName(card);
    ImageWrapper textureForCard = loader.getImageForPath("cards/" + textureString + ".png");

    // irrelevant for libgdx, but I'll post it, so you see what happens
    faceUpCards.put(textureString, textureForCard);

    return textureForCard;
}
[...]
private ImageWrapper getImageForPath(String path) {
        try {
            return new ImageWrapper(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(path)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine in most cases, but not in all.

I also tried to reload the stage with

```
Group root = stage.getRoot();
stage.clear();
stage.setRoot(root);
```

as specified [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html#setRoot-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group-). But that does not fix the problem.

Comment: Update: I found, that the current version is 1.9.5, changed that, but neither that nor using the code where I set the root, changes anything about the problem.

Comment: show me code of your draw method of cardImage class ?

Comment: The question title does not match the problem you described at the end (setRoot not known). What exactly is the problem? Are you getting a compile error? Runtime error or something else?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan: cardImage is of class Image, I did not touch the draw-method

Comment: @munyul: The readding of the root was a try to fix it, but as I commented I managed to do that, but it does not fix the problem (which is that my texture is not added, but instead is completely black...)

I'll edit the question so it becomes clearer.

Comment: @Isabella show me your code, how you create object of your cardImage ?

Comment: @Isabella black boxes can happen if the texture is not loaded properly. A reason for that might be, that you load the texture in a thread other than the GL Render thread, or you lose GL context (for example when you minimize the app). Please provide the code where you load your images for further help :)

Comment: @Isabelle where and when in your app do you call `loadActorForCardAndSaveInMap`? And what is `loader.getImageForPath` doing?

Comment: @TobiasG: Thank you for that hint, but that is not the case. The procedure I want to do is exactly the same what I can do manually. The user can either do a move manually or he can use a button to give him a hint (which at the moment also makes the move it wants to hint at). In the class that extends ApplicationAdapter this results in exactly the same code that is executed and which works in the manual case. As said: I had that one time already when doing automated moves, but I fixed it in pre-loading the texture and setting it invisible. But that is not what I want to do.

Comment: @Isabella when it worked with pre-loading, it's pretty certain that it's a thread problem. When the user does the move, how do you intercept the input event and propagate it until you call `loadActorForCardAndSaveInMap`?

Comment: @TobiasG: That is way to complicated to be posted here. Moreover it is for a university project that should be published later, so I can not post any more code :-| . If it is a thread problem: How can I synchronize it with the thread? I tried sth like
http://pastebin.com/28w7kBEH
but that makes everything go wrong and results in an error on loading the first asset. And if I remove the 1000 from the wait, it waits endlessly. :P

Comment: @TobiasG: But thinking about your remark, I do realise, that when the user makes a move manually, it is detected by the GestureListener (inside libgdx), but when the hint-button is clicked, that event is passed down from Android. Hence your observation is most probably true. Leaves me with the question on how to synchronize with the open gl thread. I don't have a lot of experience with threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Synchronize with render thread

So as the `render()` call is in fact synchronized with the GL context, use this as entry point.

1) Define a task-list somewhere
`private ArrayList<Runnable> synchronizedTasks = new ArrayList<>();`

2) Add the synchronized calls from within the render loop to your tasks

```
public void render() {
    runSyncTasks();
    // other draw code
}

private void runSyncTasks(){
    synchronized(synchronizedTasks){
        for(Runnable r : synchronizedTasks){
            r.run();
        }
        synchronizedTasks.clear();
    }
}
```

3) When you want to load your image (e.g. on user input), submit the task like that:

```
synchronized(synchronizedTasks){
    synchronizedTasks.add(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            ... loadActorForCardAndSaveInMap(...)
        }
    });
}
```

This will add the `Runnable` to the list and it will be executed in the next `render()` pass of the GL thread. Keep in mind that you need to do any actions involving the created `ImageWrapper` object inside that `run(){}` method.

## Edit

Or indeed, you can just submit your `Runnable` via `Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable()...);` without the custom synchronizer stuff. The Gdx call does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I had problems with awaiting the result from the thread, but now found a way of execution, where I don't need to wait for a result (the outermost call was a void) and now it works like a charm.

Thank you very much!